# Why isn't navigate function passing data to new screen?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, barcodes

In PowerApps I am trying to build a function in my inventory app that will transfer data from one data card to another in a new screen when navigating, but I can't seem to get it to work. The user scans a barcode, and I want this data to be transferred to the new screen without them having to scan it again.

I am not sure if my syntax is incorrect or if the source of data is incorrect.

FYI "DataCardValue2" is the first barcode scan value. My code is below:

```
If(
    Dropdown3.Selected.Value = "Inspect & Repair" Or Dropdown3.Selected.Value = "Fail",
    Navigate('Action Required' , ScreenTransition.None,{Barcode: DataCardValue2.Text}

) Or If(
    Dropdown3.Selected.Value = "Pass",
    Navigate('Home Screen'))
);

SubmitForm('frm_WAH Inventory');
```

Comment: Try using `.Value` on barcode control instead of `.Text`. let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No that doesn't work either. 

"Incompatible type. We can't evaluate your formula because the context variable types are incompatible with the types of values in other places in your app. Name isn't valid. This identifier isn't recognised"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working solution I just tried at my end:

- I have 2 screens (Screen1 and Screen 2)
- "Navigate" button & "BarcodeScanner1" on Screen1:

[image]

- "Label1" on Screen2:

[image]

I am using below formula in **OnSelect** property of "Navigate" button:

```
Navigate(Screen2, ScreenTransition.None, {BarcodeVal: BarcodeScanner1.Value})
```

& this formula on **Text** property of "Label1" control:

```
"Barcode from Screen1: " & BarcodeVal
```

This is working as expected for me:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Barcode scanner control in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-new-barcode-scanner)

Comment: That works. I had to put "Barcode" in the default value of the new datacard. I forgot to mention that it is a text input item in a new edit form. But it works now. Thank you